# 2960X Management VLAN

Tags: cisco-catalyst, cisco-ios-15

I have a Cisco ws-c2960x-24td-l running 15.2(2)E7

I have created a management vlan (500) and want to put the management interface (FE0) into it, however the "switchport" command is not available for this interface.
Can somebody let me know what I am doing wrong please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The management port is like a routed interface, you need to set the IP directly on the interface and patch it to a network device configured with the VLAN 500.

Comment: So there is no way to logically assign it to a vlan?

Comment: No that is not possible

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can disregard the dedicated management interface and simply assign an IP address to the VLAN 500 interface on the switch and use this IP for management purpose, with appropriate access lists.

FE0 is useful for out of band management. Nothing prevent you to perform in-band management without it.

Comment: We primarily use it as a console port, where the switch has local DHCP server running with 1 IP address available in a small subnet. Then you can connect your PC directly to the management port, get an IP address and manage the switch through that without any USB to serial converter. It also removes buffering and speed issues like the console port.

Comment: The 2960 line has a USB console, btw.